# How to access ubuntu server running headlessly in virtualbox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I exported a ubuntu server (in ova format) which previously ran on my macbook.

Then I installed virtualbox on a new linux host, and re-created the ubuntu vm by importing the ova file.

Now I want to access the ubuntu vm (headless started), but I got no GUI system on the linux host.

So I think maybe I can use some kind of VNC to get my hands on its console. I tried installing the virtualbox-extension-pack so I can start the vm with `vrde` enabled. However, connecting from my macbook using `rdesktop -a 16 -N <linux-host-ip>:3389` failed, it said `ERROR: Failed to open display: :0.0`.

After digging a lot with google, still don't know what to do next, can anyone help?

Comment: The `ERROR: Failed to open display: :0.0` is probably referring to X11... are you running `rdesktop` on the remote (headless) linux machine, or on your local workstation? (run it locally)

Comment: You can also enable and x11 forwarding and install and configure `tigervnc-server` on the virtual machine and `tigervnc` on the host if you want a GUI or install `rdesktop` on your client and enable `X11` forwarding.

Comment: @Attie I run rdesktop on my local macbook, not linux host and not ubuntu vm.

Comment: @NasirRiley The problem is I can't access my virtual machine any way right now, that's why I want a vnc kind of thing for it...

Comment: @dastan Is `ssh` enabled and configured on the machine? If it is then you can use that to install `tigervnc-server` on the Ubuntu VM and `tigervnc` on the Linux host. If not then there's not a whole lot that you can do other than configuring things on your Macbook and then importing again to your Linux host.

Comment: @NasirRiley Well I just modified the host-only network's CIDR, so I can get to access the ubuntu vm's static ip address now. Then I can ssh into it and do everything else. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.